# retrieve users who are not blocked (many to many relationship)

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel app users can block other users (via many to many relationship), however when I retrieve users **I still GET BLOCKED USERS** in results.

I do know for certain users are getting blocked succesfully since I print $blockedUserIds results, **so the problem might be in the query itself**.

I retrieve non blocked users like this (still get blocked ones sadly):

```
$blockedUserIds = $user->blockedusers()->get()->pluck('id');

User::select('*')
->when(count($blockedUserIds)>0, function($query) use ($blockedUserIds)
        {
            $query->whereDoesntHave("blockedusers", function ($query) use ($blockedUserIds)
            {
                $query->whereIn("blocked_id",$blockedUserIds);
            });
        })
->get();
```

How I add a blocked user to users:

```
        $user = User::with('blockedusers')->findOrFail($request['reporter_id']);

        $blocked_id = $request['reported_id'];
    
        $user->blockedusers()->attach($blocked_id);
```

Blocked users migration (many to many relationship):

```
Schema::create('blockedusers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('blocker_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('blocker_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('blocked_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('blocked_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Another question, should I call save after I attach?

Comment: Please share the relations you set on your `Model`. Also, is there a `friends` mechanism on your app where someone becomes *friend* with another ?

Answer (score 0):

As ths said in their comment, it would have been useful if you included the `blockedusers` relationship in your question.
Nonetheless I had a look at your query, assuming the following relationship on the User model:

```
public function blockedusers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'blockedusers', 'blocker_id', 'blocked_id');
    }
```

If your relationship is different then this might not be helpful to you. In that case please provide your relationship.

That being said.
One way to achieve what you want would be by replacing your entire query by:

```
$users = User::whereNotIn('id', $blockedUserIds)->get();
```

If you also want to check if the user has any blocked users, you can achieve that in a less verbose way:

```
count($blockedUserIds) ? $users = User::whereNotIn('id', $blockedUserIds)->get() : $users = User::all();
```

If you also want to exclude the current user, then you can do:

```
count($blockedUserIds) ? $users = User::whereNot('id',$user->id)->whereNotIn('id', $blockedUserIds)->get() : $users = User::whereNot('id',$user->id)->get();
```